# Add 'this' on plus-minus inputs via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<form id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
</form>
```

I have an input with plus and minus function on my Bootstrap site. Its called custom js and working fine.

But If I have two inputs in one page, working together. However, it must be separate.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/puJ6G/2455/)

How can I fix it?

Comment: @Ramanlfc if you check the demo, you can see, it has a different id.

Comment: Use `prev()` on minus click and `next()` on plus click [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/puJ6G/2456/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jquery `.siblings` and select an input which is the sibling of button .

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puJ6G/2457/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // This button will increment the value
  $('.qtyplus').click(function(e) {
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($(this).siblings('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    // If is not undefined
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      // Increment
      $(this).siblings('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
      // Otherwise put a 0 there
      $(this).siblings('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
  });
  // This button will decrement the value till 0
  $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($(this).siblings('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
      // Decrement one
      $(this).siblings('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
      // Otherwise put a 0 there
      $(this).siblings('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#myform {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
  margin: 2%;
}
.qty {
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
input.qtyplus {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
input.qtyminus {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
  <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
  <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
  <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
</form>
<form id='myform2' method='POST' action='#'>
  <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
  <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
  <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
</form>
```

Comment: @Tushar Sure. I'll do.

Comment: Thank you, yes its working but now, I have very weird problem. When I replace minus and plus its not working. Can you check it? http://jsfiddle.net/puJ6G/2458/

Comment: @JonathanD. That is Tushar answer. The problem is you changed the position of your buttons element. Change it to `qtyminus qty  qtyminus` to work.